# BS4 python add tag error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to add a  tag on a new line under my  tag ton a new line using BS4 but am getting an error of

```
c:\PDW\Logfiles>bs.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PDW\Logfiles\bs.py", line 10, in <module>
    title.insert_after(meta)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert_after'
```

and here is python code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup


soup = Soup(open("filter2.html"))

head = soup.find('HEAD')
meta = soup.new_tag('META')
meta['content'] = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
meta['http-equiv'] = "Content-Type"
title.insert_after(meta)

print soup
```

and my HTML file

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="none">
<LINK REL="stylesheet" HREF="a.css" TYPE="text/css">
</HEAD>
```

I'm not sure what is wrong. I've look at docs and all seems correct. 
any ideas ?

there is not TITLE tag it doesn't need one as its a webpage that wont be used by many people just myself and family

Comment: What's `title`? The variable is not defined in your code snippet.

Comment: As @Sudipta mentions - how are you setting `title`? I'd expect a `NameError` from your code snippet...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

solved it. after a bit more google and a cup of coffee

now complete

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

soup = Soup(open("filter2.html"))

head = soup.find('head')
metatag = soup.new_tag('meta')
metatag.attrs['http-equiv'] = 'Content-Type'
metatag.attrs['content'] = 'text/html'
soup.head.append(metatag)

html = soup.prettify("utf-8")
with open("filter2.html", "wb") as file:
    file.write(html)
```

Comment: main issue was having `title.insert_after(meta)` not `head.insert_after(meta)` but then found a better way

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful Soup automatically guesses and changes the invalid HTML markups into valid HTML markups. Thereby changing `<HEAD>` to `<head>`.

```
soup = Soup(open("filter2.html"))

head = soup.find('head')
title = soup.new_tag('title')
title.insert(1, "Some Title")
head.insert(1, title)
```

And I suggest that you properly use the HTML tags to avoid headache.